# Spatial analysis and clustering near features

Tags: clustering

Im working on marking behaviour in group living animals and im interested in how marking behaviour is affected by certain characteristics of the neighbouring groups. I have plotted the territories of each group from 95% density isopleths created using a-LoCoH. The marks of each individual from a group are plotted as a separate points layer. Marking behaviour does not appear to be random, and they do seem to cluster around boundaries with neighbouring groups. What I would like to investigate whether individuals mark more near some groups than near others, for example, do individuals mark less near groups that are closely related? is it possible to show that points are clustering near some features but not near others?

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated,

Dave Humphries

##### update

For demonstration, below is an image of four territories (A,B,C, and D) and the marking locations of two individuals from group A. Groups A and B are closely related. Groups C and D are unrelated to group A.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to supply sample data?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to stack exchange - and GIS for that matter, what is the standard format to supply sample data? ArcMap document?

Comment: Sample data should be published in a open GIS format readable by many GIS systems.

Comment: Some of the files involved are shapefiles and as i understand it there is no way currently of sharing these types of files on SE. I am happy to supply examples via e-mail at: david.humphries@mq.edu.au

Comment: Another question while I'm thinking about this (back off holidays) - are the a-LoCoH  boundaries produced from the same marking dataset, or a different dataset altogether? Also, what kind of software are you using (and do you have access to)?

Comment: I have access to both R and ArcGIS. I am plotting territories in R, and have moved the shapefiles into ArcGIS. The marking points are recorded separately. I have one database of point locations for movements, and a separate file for marking locations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend taking a look at [R](http://www.r-project.org/), in particular the [spatstat package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html) from CSRIO. There's an excellent [manual/tutorial by Prof. Adrian Baddeley](http://www.csiro.au/resources/pf16h) available which will take you through a host of different methods for point pattern analysis. Particulraly I'd take a look at the Part VII: Marked Point Patterns (specifically the Mark correlation function on page 202). *Note* marks here refer to data being classified by an attribute instead of having a numerical relationship.

There's also a chapter on reading data in (using [rgdal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html), [sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html) etc.) at the beginning of the document. If you're using ArcGIS I'd take a look at the [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/) as one way to link between data in R and ArcGIS, otherwise QGIS has [manageR](http://www.ftools.ca/manageR/) which will do the same.

Lastly @whuber (among many others) here on GIS SE has a huge amount of experinece in R, so ask questions as you find them or try and grab him in the chat.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions. I'll try the spatstat package and see how i go.